# Sort order items by SKU in Woocommerce admin order pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm stumped if it's possible. I have scouted to only seeing results to **sort by SKU** on the front end. not the backend. When you edit an order, I want there to be an SKU column that I can sort by **ASC/DESC**. Is there a plugin out there that achieves this, or a snippet of code that can add in an additional column? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is an image illustrating the SKU I'm talking about and would love for it to be moved/duplicated into its own column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_order_get_items', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_get_items( $items, $order, $types = 'line_item' ) {

    if(count($items) < 2) return $items;

    if( $types != 'line_item') return $items;

    $item_skus = $sorted_items = array();

    // Loop through order line items
    foreach( $items as $items_id => $item ){
        // Check items type: for versions before Woocommerce 3.3
        if($item->is_type('line_item')){
            $product = $item->get_product(); //
            $item_skus[$product->get_sku()] = $items_id;
        }
    }
    // Check items type: for versions before Woocommerce 3.3 (2)
    if( count($item_skus) == 0 ) return $items;

    // Sorting in ASC order based on SKUs;
    ksort($item_skus); // or use krsort() for DESC order

    // Loop through sorted $item_skus array
    foreach( $item_skus as $sku => $item_id ){
        // Set items in the correct order
        $sorted_items[$item_id] = $items[$item_id];
    }
    return $sorted_items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@mujuonly has a great answer. I was using it until I found a conflict with woocommerce subscription renewals. The original orders were fine, but renewals orders were missing their shipping method.

Instead I opted to sort the basket items by sku so that they would be saved in the database that way.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'sort_cart_items_sku' );

function sort_cart_items_sku() {

    // READ CART ITEMS
    $products_in_cart = array();
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $item ) {
        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $item['data']->get_sku();
    }

    // SORT CART ITEMS
    natsort( $products_in_cart );

    // ASSIGN SORTED ITEMS TO CART
    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
        $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
    }
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

}
```

Credit: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-sort-cart-items-alphabetically-az/